# Magento 2 view order issue

Tags: magento2, sales-order, magento2.3.2

We are using Magento 2.3.2 version.We are facing issue when we go to Sales --> Order and  click on view  orders the below error comes up. The  error is  not coming  with pending orders but coming  with completed / In process or cancelled orders. The error we get is below

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: Division by zero in /home/websites/public_html/vendor/magento/module-weee/Block/Item/Price/Renderer.php on line 207

Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: Division by zero in /home/websites/public_html/vendor/magento/module-weee/Block/Item/Price/Renderer.php on line 207
<pre>#1 Magento\Weee\Block\Item\Price\Renderer->getBaseUnitDisplayPriceExclTax() called at [vendor/magento/module-weee/Block/Adminhtml/Items/Price/Renderer.php:77]
#2 Magento\Weee\Block\Adminhtml\Items\Price\Renderer->getUnitPriceExclTaxHtml() called at [vendor/magento/module-weee/view/adminhtml/templates/items/price/unit.phtml:25]
#3 include('/home/websites/s...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php:59]
#4 Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(&Magento\Weee\Block\Adminhtml\Items\Price\Renderer#000000001f54bb8b00000000102aeb83#, '/home/websites/s...', array()) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php:271]
#5 Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('/home/websites/s...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php:301]
```

Comment: Are you use any extension or customised view order page ?

Comment: It seems when your order status is changed the ordered qty is becoming zero for any one/all product(s). Could you please check in database for the order which you have issue that there is any order_item with `qty_ordered` as 0. Check in table `sales_order_item` & column `qty_ordered`.